# Programmatically made button cannot change hover color c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I cannot find a way to change the *hover color* when delopying it *programmatically* in c# winforms.

I hope someone can help me!

Code:

```
Button btn = new Button
{
    Name = "btn1",
    Width = 250,
    Height = 250,
    Location = new Point(0, 15),
    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
    BackgroundImage = img,
    BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
};
```

Comment: How would you do that in a normal, design time created, button?

Comment: You could build a Custom Control that implements the functionality internally, so you don't need to bother, all behaviors are applied automatically and configurable through Properties.  No need to add/remove event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

use `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` for change background color in button

```
 Button btn = new Button
 {
    Name = "btn1",
    Width = 250,
    Height = 250,
    Location = new Point(0, 15),
    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
    BackgroundImage = img,
    BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
  };
  btn.MouseEnter += OnMouseEnter;
  btn.MouseLeave += OnMouseLeave;


  private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
  }
  private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
  }
```

Comment: Probably we should *restore* the initial button's `BackColor` in `OnMouseLeave`: `button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` (not `SystemColors.ButtonFace`)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the hover color *outside* of the initialization block:

```
 // We create button 
 Button btn = new Button
 {
    ...
 }  

 // And then specify hovering behaviour

 // Blue while hovering
 btn.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Blue;

 // Red when pressing (uncomment if you want)
 // btn.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Red;
```